# Difference between glob() and iglob() functions in the glob module

Tags: python, glob

I needed to use the glob module to list files with a certain regex and it worked perfectly with `glob()`.
When i went through the documentation of the module, I saw another function `globi()`. It was mentioned that `iglob()` returns an iterator. Can someone please explain what that means?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-pythons-iterator-iterable-and-iteration-protocols

Comment: Since you were reading the [`iglob()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.iglob), there's a link to [iterator](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterator) right there.

Comment: Thanks for your help peeps!!